# iTextSharp BarcodePDF417, how to handle barcode with 2000 characters or more encoded in text

Tags: itext, barcode

I'm trying to encoding more than 2000 characters in a barcode.

```
Random random = new Random();
const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
var text = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 2000)
    .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
var barcode = new BarcodePDF417();
barcode.SetText(text);
barcode.GetImage();
```

When trying to GetImage(), I recieve an Error.

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'The text is too big.')'
```

I understand that there is a Macro version where you can link data. However, the resulting barcode is no longer uniform. I want just 1 scannable barcode. Is this achievable using ITextSharp?

```
barcode.MacroFileId = "0"
barcode.MacroSegmentId = someIndexinLoop;
barcode.MacroSegmentCount = totalCount;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible within a single PDF417 complaint barcode.

You could use multiple barcodes or a link to more data as suggested, or if you have control over the application that will be reading the barcode then you can employ fancy tricks like short-codes within the barcode that can be expanded to some pre-set string by the application doing the scanning.

The PDF417 specification as shown in the ISO spec, or [here](https://www.morovia.com/manuals/PDF417-Font-ware-Writer-SDK-4/chapter.overview.php) does have limits:

> PDF417 is capable of encoding more than **1100 bytes, 1800 text**
> **characters** or 2710 digits. Large data files can be encoded into a
> series of linked PDF417 symbols using a standard methodology referred
> to as Macro PDF417.

And there is some great information [here](https://www.barcodefaq.com/2d/pdf417/#Modes):

> It is recommended to limit the amount of data in each 2D barcode
> symbol to 800 characters or less, using 20 columns or less. Although
> the specification states that “up to 1100 bytes or 1800 ASCII
> characters can be encoded in a PDF417 symbol,” **it is not usually
> achievable**. **The amount of data that can be encoded will vary
> depending upon the type of data, the compaction type, the error
> correction level chosen and the limitation of the scanner being
> used**. For example, in text compaction mode, the amount of compaction
> varies due to mode **switching between different types of
> characters**, such as between numbers, upper case, lower case and
> punctuation. In addition, many PDF417 CCD scanners do not reliably
> read more than 800 to 850 characters and some scanners have limits of
> only 300 characters.